# Using Flutter Provider package Selector widget rebuilds unnecessary widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

When I update a `ChangeNotifier` class instance variable using `Provider.of<T>(context, listen: true).value` all `Selector` widgets dependent on that class are rebuilt (as if I used a `Consumer` rather than a `Selector` widget). If I update an instance variable using `Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false).value` the `Selector` widget and associated `selector:` parameter correctly update only the widgets dependent upon the changed data

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(AppMain());

class ModState with ChangeNotifier {
  int _counter0 = 0;
  int get counter0 => _counter0;
  set counter0(int _value) {
    _counter0 = _value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int _counter1 = 0;
  int get counter1 => _counter1;
  set counter1(int _value) {
    _counter1 = _value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

    int get counter012 => (_counter0 + _counter1);

  static ModState of(BuildContext context, {bool listen = true}) =>
      Provider.of<ModState>(context, listen: listen);
}

class AppMain extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => ModState())],
        child: MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(
            // Wrap in Builder Widget to clarify context
            body: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return SafeArea(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Tooltip(
                  message: 'Update counter 0, rebuild counter 0 Text widget',
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Counterintuitively, user Provider.of<mode>(context, listen: false) to avoid rebuilding all children
                      ModState.of(context, listen: false).counter0++;
                      debugPrint(
                          'Counter0: button pressed ${ModState.of(context, listen: false).counter0}');
                    },
                    child: Text('Update 0, rebuild 0'),
                  ),
                ),
                Selector<ModState, int>(
                  selector: (_, _state) => _state.counter0,
                  builder: (_, _data, __) {
                    debugPrint(
                        'Counter0, builder invoked ${ModState.of(context, listen: false).counter0}');
                    return Text(
                        '$_data / ${ModState.of(context, listen: false).counter012}');
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Tooltip(
                  message: 'Update counter 1, rebuild counter 1 Text widget',
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Counterintuitively, user Provider.of<mode>(context, listen: false) to avoid rebuilding all children
                      ModState.of(context, listen: false).counter1++;
                      debugPrint(
                          'Counter1: button pressed ${ModState.of(context, listen: false).counter1}');
                    },
                    child: Text('Update 1, rebuild 1'),
                  ),
                ),
                Selector<ModState, int>(
                  selector: (_, _state) => _state.counter1,
                  builder: (_, _data, __) {
                    debugPrint(
                        'Counter1, builder invoked ${ModState.of(context, listen: false).counter1}');
                    return Text(
                        '$_data / ${ModState.of(context, listen: false).counter012}');
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ]));
        }))));
  }
}
```

While my now code works, using the `listen: false` parameter is counter-intuitive in terms of my understanding of that parameter. I would like to understand why, so that I can improve my code in general

Comment: More specifically, your question is "Why is calling Provider.of inside the onPressed of a button making the widgets rebuild more often?"? Or I am missing something?

Comment: related https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/40491.

Comment: Under the circumstances I am happy at the moment to track issue #40491
 
Does it matter? As a new flutter programmer I am trying to follow what I understand as "best practice", which is to limit widget rebuilds. The Selector widget, from my point of view, makes very little sense except to reduce widget rebuilds 
 
Maybe I understand it all wrong?

Comment: Your question is actually unrelated to Selector. Not directly at least. In your case it is not Selector that rebuilds, but Builder.

Comment: Thanks for your responses so far. I need to think on that for a while. And my time zone is catching up with me

Comment: @TonyT have you found any solution/workaround that you can share to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From what has been mentioned on this post, `Selector` is working as expected. As mentioned in the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector-class.html), the Widget will rebuild when there's a change on `selector(BuildContext, A)`. What seems to happen here is the entire `Widget build()` gets rebuilt. Then again, if the data displayed on the Widgets are correct and there's no performance issues, then it's passable. However, if you'd like to prevent rebuilds, you may want to reconsider how Provider is laid out on the page.